# Can we present a translucence ViewController like UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to encapsulate a translucence ViewController just like UIAlertController named CQAlertController.In the `viewDidLoad` method of CQAlertController I had written:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
```

But when I use present CQAlertController in rootViewController:

```
CQAlertController *alertController = [CQAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"detail" preferredStyle:CQAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

it didn't present a translucence ViewController but a total black ViewController.

Is there any way to present a translucence ViewController?

**NOTE:**

1. The method `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated` is deprecated so I don't want to use this method at all.
2. The goal I want to get is use method `presentViewController:animated:`to **present a translucence ViewController directly** just like present UIAlertController.

What should I do for CQAlertController?

Comment: Can you please share code, how you're presenting the cqAlertController with an instance?

Comment: Please add your code in your question not in the comments. It helps for everyone.

Comment: @Imad OK,finished.Please try again.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CQAlertController *alertController = [CQAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"detail" preferredStyle:CQAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know the way you said but I just want to present the translucence ViewController directly without write modalPresentationStyle.Thank you very much anyway.